# Set binding on button tooltip with a declared instance of a user control as source

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls, tooltip

I've added a user control (with labels and textboxes) to my WPF project shown here:

`<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.myControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="384" Width="543">
    <Grid x:Name="_LabelServerURL">
        <Label x:Name="_LabelServerUrl" Content="Server Url:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="60,21,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="_TextboxUrl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="158,22,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="235"/>
        <Label x:Name="_LabelURLExample" Content="(https://promodel.com)" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="398,21,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="139"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>`

and have created an instance of that user control in my main window code behind.

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private myControl _settings = new myControl();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AddStackPanelChildren();
        _ButtonEPSSettings.ToolTip = _epsSettings;
        //SetButtonTootips();
    }
```

In my main window I have a list of buttons, and I want to set their tooltip property (or bind the tooltip property) to the instance of my user control so that the tooltip dynamically updates when I add values to the textboxes in my user control. So far in my main window xaml I've been able to show my user control as the tooltip shown here:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Controls ="clr-namespace:MyProject" <!--Declare project namespace-->
    Title="EPS Configuration Manager" Height="415" Width="766">
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="_ButtonSettings" 
            Content="EPS Settings" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="10,10,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="199" 
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
            BorderThickness="0"  
            Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" Click="_ButtonSettings_Click"
            >
        <Button.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="384" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="543" Name="_StackPanelEPSSettings">
                    <Controls:myControl/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ToolTip>
        </Button.ToolTip>
    </Button>
```

I am still not clear on setting that tooltip as the instance of my user control as declared in my main window code behind. Any help will go a long way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set tooltips in backgroud, don't use these code:

```
<Button.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="384" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="543" Name="_StackPanelEPSSettings">
                    <Controls:myControl/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ToolTip>
</Button.ToolTip>
```

If you want the tooltip dynamically updates:

```
private myControl mytooltip = new myControl();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AddStackPanelChildren();
        mytooltip._TextboxUrl.Text = "Hello";
        _ButtonEPSSettings.ToolTip = mytooltip;
        //SetButtonTootips();
    }
```

Comment: I have taken your advice but I am getting an unhandled exception when I the tooltip should be opening up. "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Must disconnect specified child from current parent Visual before attaching to new parent Visual."

Comment: public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private myControl _myTooltip = new myControl();        

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AddStackPanelChildren();
            PopulateDictionary();
            _myTooltip._TextboxEPSUrl.Text = "hello";
            _ButtonEPSSettings.ToolTip = _myTooltip;
            //SetButtonTootips();
        }

Comment: sorry，I can't understand `AddStackPanelChildren` and `PopulateDictionary` so far.Could you post your project or make a simple example?

Comment: I figured out what the issue was. My method AddStackPanelChildren() right after I initialized the main window was adding my user control instance to the main window stack panel, so when I tried adding that instance to a tool tip it couldn't because my user control instance was already a child of the stack panel. I removed that method, and added the instance on the button click event instead (used managing methods to do this).